# Plot groups based on unique tag

Tags: plotting

I have a [.csv file](https://github.com/bhargavarama/data) that has 12 columns and 511 rows.

```
data = Import["C:\\Users\\Documents\\data\\AllResults\\result1.csv"];
```

The first two columns are id tags. I want to plot the last 10 columns of each row as a separate step function.

```
Do[Print[DiscretePlot[data[[i, k + 2]], {k, 1, 10}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, ExtentSize -> All,
PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}}]], {i, 511}]
```

(Please feel free to make it prettier)

Now I want to create multiple plots for each unique id in column 1. For example, The first 3 rows of the data have the same column 1 id ("1000_0.01"). I want 4 plots for this id, all in one row, side by side. The first 3 plots are the `DiscretePlot`s of each of the 3 rows in the data and the 4th plot is the summary plot that contains all the 3 plots earlier.

**Note:** The data is sorted by the first column, so there is no need for searching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions:

```
plot =
 ListLinePlot[#, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Filling -> Bottom,
 InterpolationOrder -> 0,  PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}}, ImageSize -> 200] &;

row[id_, dat_List] := Join[{id}, plot /@ dat, {plot@dat}]
```

Data:

```
data = Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bhargavarama/data/master/result1.csv"];
```

Usage:

```
row[#[[1, 1]], #[[All, -10 ;;]]] & /@ Partition[data, 3][[37 ;; 39]] // Grid
```

[image]

The part specification `[[37 ;; 39]]` was just to restrict the range for the example.  You can remove it to plot *all* data.

Note: this code was written assuming there are always three records per tag.  For an arbitrary number of records you may use:

```
row[#[[1, 1]], #[[All, -10 ;;]]] & /@ GatherBy[data, First][[37 ;; 39]] // Grid
```

Comment: You never stop to amaze me with your elegant ways!! `plot` and `row` functions are neat!! Thank you. +1

Comment: @brama Thanks, and you're welcome.